# Scanning a file for a pattern

Tags: java, regex, file, java.util.scanner

I'm currently working on a simple parsing program which reads certain patterns out of a file, formats them and then write them into an output file.

The input files look like this

> {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,} {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3}

The number of digits vary from block to block and also the digits themselves 
are basically random. 
So I'd like to scan the input file for those blocks.
This is what I got so far:

```
Pattern block = Pattern.compile("(\\{.*\\})");
    while(scanner.hasNext(block)){
        System.out.println(scanner.next(block));
    }
```

But so far, the program doesn't even enter the `while` statement. I don't know
if my pattern is wrong or if I'm using the Scanner incorrectly.

And how do I take care of this whitespace between the blocks?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are each block in a different row of the file?

Comment: nope, unfortunately not.

Comment: Are like you put above? And how have to be stored? All of them concatenated?

Comment: I think I kind of spotted the mistake. The blocks actually do have whitespaces after every comma. Is there a way to ignore that whitespace?

Comment: I have a doubt. What type of Scanner have you open?

Comment: It's java.util.scanner

Comment: Yes, but I mean what constructor of Scanner have you used. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html. There are a lot of differents.

Comment: Sorry! "new Scanner(File io)"

Comment: I don't know anything about regex so please can you tell me what retrieves your regex sentence? It retrieves all the blocks or just one?

Comment: Okay after several trials... it's definitely the whitespace. {0,0,0,0,0} is totally okay but {0, 0, 0, 0, 0} fails. how can I parse that?

Comment: I suppose that each time you call to the Pattern it makes reference to an unique block, that's right? Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, sorry! my regex is: (\\{)(.*|\\s*)(\\{) It works for {0,0,0,0,0,0,0} but not for {0, 0, 0, 0,}

Comment: Ok, it was I wanted to know. What exactly it returns to you. I'm sorry but I don't know anything about regex. I will put an answer now with a possible solution that I think it could solve your problem.

Comment: Well, thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Before initialize the `Pattern` if all the blocks have a space inside of them in the file, what I think that could be a possible solution its to read the file and replace all the spaces to a "" in the total `String`.

What I mean, for example, if you have stored your blocks in your file as a `String` like this (that it's only in one line):

```
{0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 } {1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,} {3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3 }
```

then you can read it with:

```
String test = scanner.nextLine();
```

and now that you have your `String` with all the blocks you can replace your `" "` to `""`. Something like this:

```
test = test.replaceAll(" ","");
```

Now you can print it in another file and read this second file to get all the blocks without the space.

I expect it will helps to you!

Answer (score 0):

Define the *delimiter* - the pattern *between* tokens:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("(?<=\\{)\\s*(?=\\{)");
```

Then to loop simply:

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String term = scanner.next();
    // term will look like "{0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 }"
}
```